# compile error for `subxt-signer` version 0.30: use of unstable library feature 'once_cell'

Tags: subxt

I was testing with subxt and used the latest version. But I encountered this error:

```rust
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'once_cell'
   --> .cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/subxt-signer-0.30.1/src/utils.rs:37:21
    |
37  |                   VAR.get_or_init(|| { $expr }).clone()
```

When I explicitly ran the [tx_basic.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/subxt/examples/tx_basic.rs) in the subxt project itself, it failed:

````rust
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'once_cell'
   --> signer/src/utils.rs:22:29
    |
22  |                   static VAR: std::sync::OnceLock<$ty> = std::sync::OnceLock::new();
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
   ::: signer/src/crypto/secret_uri.rs:125:1
    |
125 | / once_static! {
126 | |     /// Interpret a phrase like:
127 | |     ///
128 | |     /// ```text
...   |
151 | |     }
152 | | }
    | |_- in this macro invocation
    |
    = note: see issue #7
````

I'm using `rustc 1.68.0-nightly (bdb07a8ec 2022-12-11)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be able to run with the latest, so do `rustup update`

Comment: Yup; `OnceCell` was added in Rust 1.70. We recently updated our MSRV as it was pointed out that it was somewhat out of date with reality :)